# Best methods for filesharing with Civi, not using file upload fields

Tags: custom-fields, files, filesystem

I'm trying to find a way to share documents in an organisation without using the file upload field as part of custom data on a contact/ case record.

Could a link field handle a link to a shared server/file system/ dropbox thing instead?

Interested in hearing how other organisations tackle this issue.

Comment: There's an extension called Documenten, I think, which handles documents. Worth a look

Comment: To be honest I'd rather not have the documents in the database file system, just be able to link across.